# Excel COUNTIFS with mixed dates and logicals

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate the number of items between two dates AND where a yes/no field is Yes

I've come up with this:

```
=COUNTIFS( $O$1:$O$601,"=Yes",$D$2:$D$601,"<September 9, 2013 20:00",$D$2:$D$601,">September 9, 2013 17:45")
```

This gives a #VALUE! result, even though either of these work

```
=COUNTIFS( $O$1:$O$601,"=Yes")
=COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$601,"<September 9, 2013 20:00",$D$2:$D$601,">September 9, 2013 17:45")
```

is there a limitation on mixing types of comparisons?

Comment: Are you sure the latter two functions are working properly?

Comment: whoops, no I'm not. it should have been o2, and "Yes" no "=Yes"

Comment: did you see my answer? You need to make all ranges the same size. "=Yes" or "Yes" will do the same and you can have the range starting wherever you want when that's the only range ..... but when combining the formulas they need to be the same size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need all ranges to be the same size. Your first range starts at row 1 the others start at row 2 - if you make them all start at row 2 it should work OK

`=COUNTIFS($O$2:$O$601,"=Yes",$D$2:$D$601,"<September 9, 2013 20:00",$D$2:$D$601,">September 9, 2013 17:45")`

Comment: Are the dates really being considered as such? I'm under the impression that they are interpreted as text instead. I guess the tick means 'yes' :)

Comment: No, that will work as long as the dates are in a valid format for your region - e.g. that won't work for me because in the UK `mmmm d, yyyy hh:mm` isn't a valid format but it should work with US regional settings. For that reason it might be better to use DATE+TIME functions - that will work irrespective of region

Answer (score 0):

From the Excel Help for the function `COUNTIFS`:

Each additional range must have the same number of rows and columns as the `criteria_range1` (first range) argument. The ranges do not have to be adjacent to each other.

So you need to make them the same size.